# C++ application collapsing after some hours

Tags: php, c++, c, linux, centos

i have an application written in C++ that uses opencv 2.0, curl and a opensurf library. First a PHP script (cron.php) calls proc_open and calls the C++ application (called icomparer). When it finishes processing N images returns groups saying which images are the same, after that the script uses:

```
shell_exec('php cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');  
die;
```

And starts again. Well, after 800 or 900 iterates my icomparer starts breaking. The system don't lets me create more files, in icomparer and in the php script.

```
proc_open(): unable to create pipe Too many open files (2)
shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'php cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

And curl fails too:

```
couldn't resolve host name (6)
```

Everything crashes. I think that i'm doing something wrong, for example, I dunno if starting another PHP process from a PHP process release resources.

In "icomparer" I'm closing all opened files. Maybe not releasing all mutex with mutex_destroy... but in each iterator the c++ application is closed, I think that all stuff is released right?

What I have to watch for? I have tried monitoring opened files with stof.

---

- Php 5.2
- Centos 5.X
- 1 GB ram
- 120 gb hard disk (4% used)
- 4 x intel xeon
- Is a VPS (machine has 16 gb ram)
- The process opens 10 threads and joins them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix-alike systems, child processes inherit the open file descriptors of the parent.  However, when the child process exits, it does close all of its *copies* of the open file descriptors but not the parent's copies.

So you are opening file descriptors in the parent and not closing them. My bet is that you are not closing the pipes returned by the `proc_open()` call.

And you'll also need to call `proc_close()` too.

Comment: Mmmmmm, I open 3 pipes, stdin "r", stdout"w" and error "a" (pointing this last one to a file). I only use the one to get app output and the error that writes to a file. I have to close the first one. File error pipe closes automatically right? (Thanks)

Comment: Not closing the first pipe (stdin "r") one is enought to break the script? The script is closed in every iterator, i think that PHP closes it automatically.

Comment: @William: Are there other file descriptors elsewhere that aren't being closed.  That is, there clearly *are* otherwise you wouldn't be running out.  You've just eleiminated one potential source of the leak.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're leaking file descriptors.

Comment: I'm using ofstream and closing them with ".close();".

Comment: You may not be leaking descriptors from C++. You could be leaking descriptors from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it looks like you're opening processes but don't close them after use and - as it seems - they are not closed automatically (which may work in some circumstances).

Make sure you close/terminate your process with [`proc_close($res)`](http://www.php.net/proc_close) if you don't use the resource anymore.

Comment: No, I use proc_close to get the output. Thanks.

Comment: How is it possible to use proc_close() to get the output? O_o As the PHP manual states: `int *exit_code* proc_close ( resource *$process* )`. Have you checked the exit code so you know the program terminated as you expected it to end?

Comment: Sorry, i get the ouput with the stdout pipe. Then I close with proc_close and save the return value :P

Answer (score -2):

Your application doesn't close it's files / sockets you can try to use the ulimit syscall with this you can remove the number of open files allowed per application. Have a look: [man ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ulimit)

Comment: Which would only mask the problem. @William You should check for open handles and close all of them before calling the shell_exec function.

Comment: I assumed that when I say that you don't close your files / sockets someone would check that out himself. :) Maybe he can't close the handles because he is still using them.

Comment: +1 to @RedX.  If you are leaking file descriptors the answer is definitely not to ignore the problem.